# What is the meaning of the "@include" in .css Files?

Tags: css, sass

I don't understand , what is the meaning of the @include tag in .css files.
For Example :

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
@include display(flex);
@include flex-direction(column);
@include align-items(center);
@include justify-content(center);
@include transition(all 2s linear);
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`@include`s are a part of SCSS, it's called Mixin. Here is an example:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
    -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
       -moz-border-radius: $radius;
        -ms-border-radius: $radius;
            border-radius: $radius;
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

`@include`s are a shortcut to storing especially things like vendor prefixes. The CSS output of the above will be:

```
.box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -ms-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
```