# css + html pulsing animation button can't figure out

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding and I am trying to add html + css together for the pulsing button effect and I added   but its just the button that pulsates and the thing around it doesn't show at all. Not too sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried a few things but can't seem to figure it out. Here's the code pen link:

```css
@import "compass/css3";

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.pulse-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: light;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5a99d4;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}
.pulse-button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    @include transform(scale(0.9));
  }
  70% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
  100% {
    @include transform(scale(0.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='pulse-button'>pulse</span>
</div>
```

---

https://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/DgGYPY

Comment: `@-webkit-keyframes pulse` <-- Don't use `@-webkit-keyframes` - [that's decades old and obsolete now. Now it's just `@keyframes`](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40keyframes).

Comment: Your `0%` keyframe style is invalid: You have `@include transform(scale(0.9));`  which is not valid CSS. [It's SASS/SCSS, which requires a built-step to produce valid CSS as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311744/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-include-in-css-files).

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is *almost there*, but you had some SCSS/SASS leftovers which aren't valid CSS, but can be trivially converted to CSS by-hand:

- [It's been a decade since `@keyframes` and `animation;` became standardised](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40keyframes), so ditch the `@-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation` prefixed syntax.
- `@include transform(scale(0.9));` is not valid CSS, just change it to `transform: scale(0.0);`
- As a general tip, you don't need `position: relative;` here, nor the `-50%` margin trick.

  - If you want to center something, [use a `flex` parent with `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
- [`height: 100%;` is an old, old trick that wreck havoc with page layout](https://greggod.medium.com/css-do-not-put-height-100-on-the-body-html-e36bda3551b3) and it's kinda obsolete now with `grid` and `flex` and `vh` units - so don't use it unless you absolutely know you need it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pulse-button {
  display: block;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: light;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;

  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5a99d4;
  cursor: pointer;

  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0.5);
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}
.pulse-button:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='pulse-button'>pulse</span>
</div>
```